# IKEv2 VPN, tunnel ok but no traffic

Tags: networking, vpn, rras, windows-server-2016, ikev2

I setup a vpn on my windows server 2016 (with routing and remote access), the client is a windows 10 pro.
This is the server configuration:

[image: Routing and remot access properties]

The client connects correctly, but does not receive a packet from the server, why?

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: I tryed to uninstall RRAS, then i rebooted the server. After the reboot I reinstalled and the VPN works! BUT on the next reboot of the RRAS service the problem reappears...

Answer (score 3):

In general, this article is pretty similar to your problem.
[Strongswan (IKEv2) connection established, but no traffic routing](https://serverfault.com/questions/593922/strongswan-ikev2-connection-established-but-no-traffic-routing)

I guess this might help you also.
`$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 ! -p esp -j SNAT --to-source` "your VPN host IP"

Comment: thanks, but I do not know:
1) What does
2) How to bring it back under windows

Comment: I haven't sonicwall, the VPN is configured by windows server 2016 routing and remote access